# Drop all observations by ID where conditions are not met

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with ~4 million transactional records, grouped by Customer_No (consisting of 1 or more transactions per Customer_No, denoted by a sequential counter). Each transaction has a Type code and I am only interested in customers where a particular combination of transaction Types were used. Neither joining the table on itself or using EXISTS in Proc Sql is allowing me to efficiently evaluate the transaction Type criteria. I suspect a data step using retain and do-loops would process the dataset faster

The dataset:

```
Customer_No Tran_Seq    Tran_Type
    0001        1           05
    0001        2           12
    0002        1           07
    0002        2           86
    0002        3           04
    0003        1           07
    0003        2           84
    0003        3           84
    0003        4           84
```

The criteria I am trying to apply:

1. All Customer_No's Tran_Type's must only be in ('04','05','07','84','86'),
   drop **all** transactions for that Customer_No if any other Tran_Type was used
2. Customer_No's Tran_Type's must include ('84' or '86') AND '04', drop **all** transactions for the Customer_No if this condition is not met

The output I want:

```
Customer_No Tran_Seq    Tran_Type
0002        1           07
0002        2           86
0002        3           04
```

Comment: Are those the only codes you need to consider or are there more? i.e. is this a simplification of the actual problem?

Comment: I would set up indicators with a retain statement to hold them across ID's, evaluate status on last.ID and then output a list of ID's.  But this isn't a code writing service so you'll need to give it a try first :).

Comment: It's a simplification. The actual codes are 3 characters and there's 122 of them. Thanks I'll try your approach

Comment: I would think proc sql works fine for this. What is the structure of your query?

Answer (score 2):

The DoW loop solution should be the most efficient if the data is sorted.  If it's not sorted, it will either be the most efficient or similar in scale but slightly less efficient depending on the circumstances of the dataset.

I compared to Dom's solution with a 3e7 ID dataset, and got for the DoW a similar (slightly less) total length with less CPU for unsorted dataset, and about 50% faster for sorted.  It is guaranteed to run in about the length of time the dataset takes to write out (maybe a bit more, but it shouldn't be much), plus sorting time if needed.

```
data want;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.customer_no);
      set have;
      by customer_no;  
      if tran_type in ('84','86') 
        then has_8486 = 1;
      else if tran_type in ('04') 
        then has_04 = 1;
      else if not (tran_type in ('04','05','07','84','86')) 
        then has_other = 1;
  end;
  do _n_= 1 by 1 until (last.customer_no);
    set have;
    by customer_no;
    if has_8486 and has_04 and not has_other then output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's that complicated. Join to a subquery, `group by Customer_No`, and put your conditions in a `having` clause. A condition in a `min` function must be true for all rows, whereas a condition in a `max` function must be true for any one row:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
  h.*
from
  have h
  inner join (
    select
      Customer_No
    from
      have
    group by
      Customer_No
    having
      min(Tran_Type in('04','05','07','84','86')) and
      max(Tran_Type in('84','86')) and
      max(Tran_Type eq '04')) h2
  on h.Customer_No = h2.Customer_No
;
quit;
```

Comment: I like this approach, but think you could do without the join and sub query entirely. Just `select * from have group by Customer_No having ...`.

Comment: You're right that it would produce the same result. I intentionally avoid that approach for two reasons: (1) It's not as clear as doing the join explicitly; other iterations of SQL won't allow this type of shortcut (for good reason, I believe). (2) in my experience, it *always* seems to take longer to run in SAS when you rely on the "remerging summary statistics" method. I don't know why it's less efficient, but that has been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I must have made a join error. On re-writing, Proc Sql completed in less than 30 seconds (on the original 4.9 million record dataset). It's not particularly elegant code though, so I'd still appreciate any improvements or alternative methods.

```
data Have;
input Customer_No $ Tran_Seq $ Tran_Type:$2.;
cards;
    0001        1           05
    0001        2           12
    0002        1           07
    0002        2           86
    0002        3           04
    0003        1           07
    0003        2           84
    0003        3           84
    0003        4           84
;
run;

Proc sql;
Create table Want as
select t1.* from Have t1
LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT Customer_No from Have
                    where Tran_Type not in ('04','05','07','84','86')
                                  ) t2
ON(t1.Customer_No=t2.Customer_No)
INNER JOIN (select DISTINCT Customer_No from Have
                    where Tran_Type in ('84','86')
                                ) t3
ON(t1.Customer_No=t3.Customer_No)
INNER JOIN (select DISTINCT Customer_No from Have
                    where Tran_Type in ('04')
                                ) t4
ON(t1.Customer_No=t4.Customer_No)
Where t2.Customer_No is null
;Quit;
```

Comment: my answer does basically this, but is a little cleaner in look.  I'm not sure which will run fastest.  if you are able, try creating an index on TRAN_TYPE as it might help in the sub -queries.

Comment: I think you have a logic issue in your code here.  The LEFT JOIN for the first part will not filter out Customer 001.  The table you get is correct, but that is because it is filtered out later.  This will cause a problem in the larger table when you have customers that pass the (84,86) and (04) test but fail the first.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a slightly less complex SQL solution than @naed555 using the INTERSECT operator.

```
proc sql noprint;

create table to_keep as
(
    select distinct customer_no
    from have 
    where tran_type in ('84','86')

    INTERSECT

    select distinct customer_no
    from have 
    where tran_type in ('04')
)

EXCEPT

    select distinct customer_no
    from have
    where tran_type not in ('04','05','07','84','86')
;

create table want as
select a.*
from have as a
inner join 
     to_keep as b
on a.customer_no = b.customer_no;

quit;
```